# Is it possible to access/change directive scope variable from parent controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Lets say I have this directive. I want to change variable of directive scope from inside of parent controller. Is it possible? Or Is this the right way to perform what I am trying to achieve.

```
<div ng-show="devices.autocompletelist.length > 0" auto-complete url="/search" model="device.name" template-url="/themes/dashboard/assets/js/angular/filter/views/autocomplete-template.html" filtertype="device" autocompletelist="devices.autocompletelist"></div>
```

Directive

```
angular.module('autocomplete.directives',[]).directive('autoComplete',['$http',function($http){
    return {
        scope:{
            selectedTagsData:'=model',
            autocompletelist: '='
        },
        restrict: 'AE',
        templateUrl: function(elem, attrs) {
            return attrs.templateUrl 
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

            // I want to access and change value of selectedTagsData.data from parent controller
            scope.selectedTagsData = {
                data: ''
            }
        },

    }
}]);
```

App

```
var app = angular.module('filterlist', ['autocomplete.directives']);
```

Controller

```
app.controller('filterCtrl', ['$rootScope', 'filterService', '$scope', '$compile', '$location', '$http', '$timeout', '$q',
function($rootScope, filterService, $scope, $compile, $location, $http, $timeout, $q) {
        $scope.deviceSelect = function(devicedata) {

            // Can I access and change value of directive scope variable 'scope.selectedTagsData.data' from here

        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: Is the `div` tag template present in the template for which `filterCtrl` is the controller?

Answer (score 0):

if you don't define **scope** in your directive, then all the $scope controller will be accessed through you directive, but this is not perfect solution, because you do not follow the separation of concern and Single Responsibility principle,
To summarize: your directive should not know anything about the parent scope and your controller should not know anything about a directive's internals. They are separate components in separate layers.

I think if you use `transclude` option it will solve your problem because transclude makes the contents of a directive with this option have access to the scope outside of the directive rather than inside.